# How to query a UTF-8 database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, utf-8

My DB2 database is using UTF-8 encoding. The source table has one colum with UTF-8 text like these lines below
Greek: Μπορώ να φάω σπασμένα γυαλιά χωρίς να πάθω τίποτα
Czech: Mohu jíst sklo, neublíží mi
Serbian: Ја могу да једем стакло
My java code is doing this (.. snipped out irrelevant parts.. )

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SAMPLE_TEXT FROM UNICODE_TEST");
File file = new File("Unicode.txt");
BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),"UTF8"));
while (rs.next()) {
    outFile.write(rs.getString("SAMPLE_TEXT"));
    outFile.write( "\n" );
}
```

The result in my file don't look like those in the source table at all.
I get this instead 
Greek:  ÎœÏ€Î¿ÏÏŽ Î½Î± Ï†Î¬Ï‰ ÏƒÏ€Î±ÏƒÎ¼Î­Î½Î± Î³Ï…Î±Î»Î¹Î¬ Ï‡Ï‰ÏÎ¯Ï‚ Î½Î± Ï€Î¬Î¸Ï‰ Ï„Î¯Ï€Î¿Ï„Î±
Czech :  Mohu jÃ­st sklo, neublÃ­Å¾Ã­ mi
Serbian:  ÐˆÐ° Ð¼Ð¾Ð³Ñƒ Ð´Ð° Ñ˜ÐµÐ´ÐµÐ¼ ÑÑ‚Ð°ÐºÐ»Ð¾ 
What did I miss?

Comment: I don't know if you are using the DB2 equivalent of nvarchar instead of varchar. Maybe you are getting the output unencoded and you need to reencode it yourself using the String class (and read the column as a byte array). Also check out if there is some parameter you need to set into the db2 database to use UTF-8.

Comment: @ Luciano. The database is defnitely UTF-8. The column is a varchar(200). I know the content is UTF-8 because I can retrieve it using a unicode aware sql query tool and it comes out exactly as I expect.

Comment: what program are you using to view the generated file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code is ok. Are you sure you your file content is wrong? What you see can appear wrong if you have your terminal wrong, for example. Can you see ok other text files in that computer encoded as UTF-8? (If you are unsure, read it in hexa, get a dump with `od`, etc). If you are sure this is not your problem, then I'd point to some charset encoding setting in the JDBC connection (no experience with DB2).

Comment: You are correct. I have the original text in one tab of Notepad++ with UTF-8 turned on. The java result set is in another tab but the concoding was set to ANSI hence the garbled appearance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database you're using, but if it's MySQL, try adding `characterEncoding=UTF-8` to your connection string.